# What is the site's policy on cross-tag possible duplicate questions?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, etiquette

I'm asking because of this question: [How do I depower Magic items that are op without ruining the immersion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/89365/23064) tagged: [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) [magic-items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-items)

With the help of Miniman, we commented a related question: [What can I do when I accidentally gave out an overpowered item?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67284/23064) tagged: [pathfinder](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinder)[gm-techniques](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gm-techniques) [magic-items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-items) [treasure](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/treasure)

I know it's not an exact duplicate but it is really really similar and the answers there could benefit the newer question.

As a potential answerer, and seeing the related question and the great answers there, I feel discouraged to write an answer that's already covered in the older question.

**What is the correct etiquette in this situation?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This comes down to whether or not the system really makes a difference to the content of answers to the new question. It may be that there are 5e specific mechanics that are applicable to the situation described in the question. If there are then the new question is not a duplicate. However, if there are no 5e specific information then the newer question is probably a duplicate.

The way this is decided is by the system experts who might answer the question, and this comes down to the vote to close process.

Answer (score 6):

1. If they are true dupes vote to close, but usually they're not.
2. Link the related question in a comment, as you have.  We don't delete those comments.
3. Go participate in the other question yourself, which will bump it onto the front page, and then others will too.
4. Bounty that other question or perform other activities to bring attention to a question in general
5. That's it.